# Send Zigbee Modules data to the server?

Tags: android, cloud, zigbee

How would I go about sending data that we receive from our adapters (Zigbee Modules) on a zigbee network to the cloud? gateway or such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to send Zigbee Modules(we use for wireless communication especially in embedded systems) data to server? If yes, There is a way to do that using any Operating system Compatible chips like Raspberry pi, BeagleBone black. I am not really sure if there are apps for android to receive data from Zigbee modules to send to your server. Hope this helps

Comment: Yes this defiantly helps! What we have is an android app which we will develop, and this app will display the information that the sensors pick up but we also want to store that information on a cloud. So, I was just wondering how is this possible.  I will look into both suggestions you have made and see if we can work with it. Thank you.

Comment: If you can make app which can display information , you can easily send that data to server. you don't even need those chips I mentioned. All you need to do is send the received data to server Asynchronously. read more about building android app with INTERNET connection. Take a server hosting at any site like godaddy or else you can use amazon aws free tier to host your server.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply.  Yes I agree on that part, building android apps I have no problem with and syncing that data to the cloud.  But each of these adapters on the network that is feeding the app with information, have a status, such as 'adapter off' or 'adapter on' etc.  And each change in the status of this adapter I want to send to the cloud.